# Get list of items from database by column value separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

I have it where the users can upload their own content, and submit keywords separated by commas. This gets put into a database like so:

```
id | display | keywords
 1 | my_item | keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4
 2 | my_item2 | keyword2,keyword5,keyword6
```

I was able to get it to search by keyword, however, I want to be able to have a page where it shows all of the keywords, in order by the ones that are used the most to ones that are used the least. This way I could have it on the sidebar and have like top 10 keywords or something like that.

How would I go about doing this?

As of now I only have the search function which is like so:

```
$items = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (display LIKE '$query%' OR keywords LIKE '%$query%') ORDER BY display ASC");
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($items)){
    if($item){
        //Display Item
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how you will decide which keyword is used most?

Comment: normalise your database. comma separated fields are horrid.